# Wider margins in align environment?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I have a set of equations in an align environment. By the time equation numbers are added, it is too wide, and goes to the next line.

I would like to shift the equations into the left margin so that each equation is only a single line

```
\begin{align}
a & =  3.64779052-4.5326958\rho+2.8254675\rho^{1.5}-1.1230973\ln(\rho)/\rho +0.02371867\ln(\rho)/\rho^2 \\
b & =  7.0399098 - 13.686034\rho-0.85088666\rho^3+2.9323443e^{\rho}+6.6465928\sqrt{\rho}\ln(\rho)\\
c & = 5.9382949+3.7429435\rho+1.108728\rho^2\ln(\rho)-0.96469546e^{\rho}+0.19983335\ln(\rho)\\
d & =  1.1350252-1.9259676\rho-1.8835841\rho^2\ln(\rho)+1.0381572\rho^3+0.00007112\ln(\rho)\\
\partial a /\partial \rho & =  2.2578288-2.6419506/\rho-0.57462084/\rho^2-0.49861017/\rho^3+0.038266286/\rho^4\\
\partial b /\partial \rho & =  -1.1150611+1.5019557\rho-1.5365115\rho^{1.5}+0.79801674\rho^3-1.2700068/\rho\\
\partial c /\partial \rho & = 2.5339359-5.0383713\rho+6.0947248\rho^{1.5}-1.3679322\rho^{2.5}+0.20489549/\rho\\
\partial d /\partial \rho & =-18.494398+17.445882\rho-16.716728\sqrt{\rho}\ln(\rho)+0.45062181/\rho^{1.5}-0.12072079/\rho^2 
\end{align}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `changepage` package and the `adjustwidth` environment as shown in the example below. (Red line indicate the margins.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{lipsum} % For dummy text. Don't use in real document.


\begin{document}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{adjustwidth}{-3cm}{0pt}
\begin{align}
a & =  3.64779052-4.5326958\rho+2.8254675\rho^{1.5}-1.1230973\ln(\rho)/\rho +0.02371867\ln(\rho)/\rho^2 \\
b & =  7.0399098 - 13.686034\rho-0.85088666\rho^3+2.9323443e^{\rho}+6.6465928\sqrt{\rho}\ln(\rho)\\
c & = 5.9382949+3.7429435\rho+1.108728\rho^2\ln(\rho)-0.96469546e^{\rho}+0.19983335\ln(\rho)\\
d & =  1.1350252-1.9259676\rho-1.8835841\rho^2\ln(\rho)+1.0381572\rho^3+0.00007112\ln(\rho)\\
\partial a /\partial \rho & =  2.2578288-2.6419506/\rho-0.57462084/\rho^2-0.49861017/\rho^3+0.038266286/\rho^4\\
\partial b /\partial \rho & =  -1.1150611+1.5019557\rho-1.5365115\rho^{1.5}+0.79801674\rho^3-1.2700068/\rho\\
\partial c /\partial \rho & = 2.5339359-5.0383713\rho+6.0947248\rho^{1.5}-1.3679322\rho^{2.5}+0.20489549/\rho\\
\partial d /\partial \rho & =-18.494398+17.445882\rho-16.716728\sqrt{\rho}\ln(\rho)+0.45062181/\rho^{1.5}-0.12072079/\rho^2 
\end{align}
\end{adjustwidth}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using the margins, I suggest to split the long lines.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{3}
a & ={} &   3.64779052 &-4.5326958\rho+2.8254675\rho^{1.5} \notag \\
  &     &              &-1.1230973\ln(\rho)/\rho +0.02371867\ln(\rho)/\rho^2 \\
b & ={} &   7.0399098  &-13.686034\rho-0.85088666\rho^3 \notag \\
  &     &              &+2.9323443e^{\rho}+6.6465928\sqrt{\rho}\ln(\rho)\\
c & ={} &   5.9382949  &+3.7429435\rho+1.108728\rho^2\ln(\rho) \notag \\
  &     &              &-0.96469546e^{\rho}+0.19983335\ln(\rho)\\
d & ={} &   1.1350252  &-1.9259676\rho-1.8835841\rho^2\ln(\rho) \notag \\
  &     &              &+1.0381572\rho^3+0.00007112\ln(\rho)\\
\smash[b]{\frac{\partial a}{\partial \rho}}
  & ={} &   2.2578288  &-2.6419506/\rho-0.57462084/\rho^2 \notag \\
  &     &              &-0.49861017/\rho^3+0.038266286/\rho^4\\
\smash[b]{\frac{\partial b}{\partial \rho}}
  & ={} &  -1.1150611  &+1.5019557\rho-1.5365115\rho^{1.5} \notag \\
  &     &              &+0.79801674\rho^3-1.2700068/\rho\\
\smash[b]{\frac{\partial c}{\partial \rho}}
  & ={} &   2.5339359  &-5.0383713\rho+6.0947248\rho^{1.5} \notag \\
  &     &              &-1.3679322\rho^{2.5}+0.20489549/\rho\\
\smash[b]{\frac{\partial d}{\partial \rho}}
  & ={} & -18.494398   &+17.445882\rho-16.716728\sqrt{\rho}\ln(\rho) \notag \\
  &     &              &+0.45062181/\rho^{1.5}-0.12072079/\rho^2 
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

With `\smash[b]` we trick LaTeX into thinking that the fractions don't extend below the baseline, so the next split line is not moved down.

[image]

Alternative way:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
a &= 3.64779052-4.5326958\rho+2.8254675\rho^{1.5} \notag \\
  &\qquad -1.1230973\ln(\rho)/\rho +0.02371867\ln(\rho)/\rho^2 \\
b &= 7.0399098-13.686034\rho-0.85088666\rho^3 \notag \\
  &\qquad +2.9323443e^{\rho}+6.6465928\sqrt{\rho}\ln(\rho)\\
c &= 5.9382949+3.7429435\rho+1.108728\rho^2\ln(\rho) \notag \\
  &\qquad -0.96469546e^{\rho}+0.19983335\ln(\rho)\\
d &= 1.1350252-1.9259676\rho-1.8835841\rho^2\ln(\rho) \notag \\
  &\qquad +1.0381572\rho^3+0.00007112\ln(\rho)\\
\smash[b]{\frac{\partial a}{\partial \rho}}
  &= 2.2578288-2.6419506/\rho-0.57462084/\rho^2 \notag \\
  &\qquad -0.49861017/\rho^3+0.038266286/\rho^4\\
\smash[b]{\frac{\partial b}{\partial \rho}}
  &= -1.1150611+1.5019557\rho-1.5365115\rho^{1.5} \notag \\
  &\qquad +0.79801674\rho^3-1.2700068/\rho\\
\smash[b]{\frac{\partial c}{\partial \rho}}
  &= 2.5339359-5.0383713\rho+6.0947248\rho^{1.5} \notag \\
  &\qquad -1.3679322\rho^{2.5}+0.20489549/\rho\\
\smash[b]{\frac{\partial d}{\partial \rho}}
  &= -18.494398+17.445882\rho-16.716728\sqrt{\rho}\ln(\rho) \notag \\
  &\qquad +0.45062181/\rho^{1.5}-0.12072079/\rho^2 
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]